# Is there something that can automatically align the equals sign (=) characters in text files?

Tags: open-source, text-processing, plain-text, plug-in

We need to align the = character in our terraform files against the longest variable name. Is there any tool that can do this automatically?

For example

```
thomas = "train"
harrypotter = "wizard"
roger = "rabbit"
```

...would become...

```
thomas      = "train"
harrypotter = "wizard"
roger       = "rabbit"
```

Bonus points: I use PyCharm primarily, so if it were a plugin for PyCharm I would be overjoyed.

Answer (score 2):

[Smart Align](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13903-smart-align) is a PyCharm plugin which does exactly that. Just,

**Windows & Linux**

1. Click into the file
2. Ctrl + a
3. Alt + ⇧ + -

**Mac**

1. Click into the file
2. ⌘ + a
3. ⌥ + ⇧ + -

Done

Answer (score 2):

Just install the ["Terraform and HCL"](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7808-terraform-and-hcl)-Plugin from Jetbrains. It also supports syntax highglighting and much more features.

After you've installed it, open your file and press "Ctrl+Alt+L" to reformat your code.

Maybe check the "Align properties" settings in Settings->Editor->Code Style->Terraform Config and there in the last tab at the right called "Other" (see screenshot). It has to be "On equals", but that is the default setting.

[image]

Comment: How do you get this plugin to align all logical blocks the same? As far as I can see, it only aligns each logical block separately.

Comment: @James I don't think the plugin can do that. The formatting is applied to blocks seperately, not equally over the whole file. Your original question didn't imply this to be a requested feature, but if you like that to happen, then Smart align might be the better solution for you :)

Comment: Thanks, and apologies for the omission. I don't suppose I might be able to ask if you know how I would add smart aline to the precommit config, could I?

Answer (score 2):

As usual - Unix shell utilities to the rescue! Specifically, [column](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html):

```
$ column -t
thomas = "train"
harrypotter = "wizard"
roger = "rabbit"

thomas         = "train"
harrypotter    = "wizard"
roger          = "rabbit"
```

And it works on files as well, of course:

```
$ cat my_file.txt
thomas = "train"
harrypotter = "wizard"
roger = "rabbit"
$ column -t my_file.txt
thomas         = "train"
harrypotter    = "wizard"
roger          = "rabbit"
```

Comment: Nice and simple!  Your answer may benefit from adding an example showing how to process input from a file.  Either way, upvoted!

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket: I thought that was obvious, but ok.

Comment: Yep, it's obvious for those of us who know how easy it is. :)